# Relying on one field in Database

Tags: database, validation, architecture

Let me give the context before I ask the question .
We work on invoicing system ,we create invoices ,validate them and pay them .

The database schema contains the following tables :

Invoices
InvoiceItems
ReceivedItems .

So we validate every invoice item quantity and check it with received item quantity .(it might be equal,lesser or greater .
The process is this way :

let say the invoice item quantity is 50 .

We have a field on invoice items called credit which is credited with  the invoice item  quantity at the time of creation .(saying that 50 quantity is to be validated )

We receive items from various sources and we update the received items as and when they come .
say we initially got  25 items .
So we decrease the credit on invoice item by 25 and mark received item as done .
Later  we get the other 25 and we validate by decreasing the credit by the remaining 25 .

So the credit is now 0.
It means the invoice is fully validated .So we send the invoice for payment .

Due to recent developer mistake following thing happened .

We were not setting the credit of invoice item to invoice item quantity .SO its basically zero while creation .
So our system thought that its validated and sent it payment .
We realized it only after two months that invoices are not getting validated .

So now we have multiple checks to reject the invoice while creation if the credit is 0.

Apart from having multiple checks ,Is there any way we can tackle this problem of highly depending on one column .
(Here the credit on the invoice items was 0 and every invoice was paid out without validation)

I am looking for any kind of solution either at the database( schema)  level or at Application level .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem sounds a bit more about the default column value. You can set that default value to null to explicit a "I don't received data on that value, yet" and go on getting that null value on account (since anything + null is set to null).

Another approach can be creating some kind of flag column to explicit say "this row was not processed yet, don't take that zero as a OK".

Also, you can validate that using some data you already got like a time stamp column or a inner join ill yield rows only in a ok condition.

For any solution is likely to drive you in both schema and app level refactoring.